# Skype-SIP gateway

Tags: gateway, asterisk, sip, skype, softphone

Does anyone know if you can setup a Skype-to-SIP gateway on your network?

I tried [Uplink](http://www.nch.com.au/skypetosip/), which works wonders, but only on Windows and with Skype on the same machine... It would be **awesome** if you could put that program on any machine and then use it as a gateway for Skype, from another machine. With port forwarding maybe?

Basically I'm trying to use Skype in Linux as a softphone for our Asterisk PBX. Are there any other solutions? Without going into Asterisk maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can keep your *Asterisk PBX* in the game, it looks like *Skype* is interested.
The [Skype for SIP Beta program](http://www.skype.com/business/form/sip-beta/) maybe what you're after. This way, any SIP or IAX2 client may have *Skype* incoming and outgoing access.

Comment: That looks awesome. Will try that, and let you know how it works. Thanks!

Comment: We weren't accepted on the program :(

Comment: We could have been accepted, we just don't want to use proprietary codecs.

Comment: Digium has now gone past beta and released a product. They charge for each simultaneous port, like a g729 codec. Works very well. Look it up at http://www.digium.com/en/products/software/skypeforasterisk.php

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like Skype for Asterisk will not be available for sale or activation after July 26, 2011. See [PC World article](http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/228690/skype_microsoft_didnt_kill_asterisk_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is already an available channel for Skype that is a Linux native, but with some limitations @ [chanskype](http://www.chanskype.com/). You must have X server and the Skype binary installed. That is, I guess the only Linux viable option, while waiting for Skype for Asterisk to come out of beta.

Answer (score 0):

Actual working options are:

Gizmo5's OpenSky Gizmo gives you a Skype username and SIP account. You use the SIP account to call Skype users and use CallOut, and Skype users can call your Skype user and reach the SIP account.

You can test for 1-5 minute calls free, and pay for longer calls.

OpenSky appears to be the easiest to setup and fairly inexpensive for a small number of connections, and looks as it matches your "Skype as a softphone" requirement.

Skypiax is another channel-per-client program for asterisk and freeswitch. Looks as if it's free, beyond your time.

Some future Skype-SIP products that might be worth looking at in the future are Skype's Skype for SIP and Digium's Skype For Asterisk, while voip-info.org has a list of other commercial VoIP-Skype gateways and a few open source ones.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Aaron's reply: [SkypeToSip](http://www.nch.com.au/skypetosip/) also works. I use it to transfer Skype calls to my asterisk box. Runs on Linux and Windows; requires Skype client; can connect to local or remote Asterisk and is free.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2014, this needs to use [Skype Connect](http://www.skype.com/en/features/skype-connect/), the other methods used when this was originally asked are no longer available